# Los sonidos personalizados parecen no cargar y no estan funcionando correctamente en expo y FCM

Tags: firebase, react-native, push-notification, expo, fcm

No se si no estoy configurando mal algo, pero no me ha estado funcionando correctamente el sonido personalizado de las notificaciones.

En mi archivo `app.json` configure `expo-notifications`, en mis plugins esta de la siguiente forma:

```
"plugins": [
  [
    "expo-notifications",
    {
      "icon": "./assets/notification-icon.png",
      "color": "#E32726",
      "sounds": ["./assets/notificacion.wav"],
      "androidMode": "default"
    }
  ],
  ...
]
```

Con esto agrege mi tono de notificación a mi proyecto, luego configure mi canal personalizado:

```
await Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync('notificaion', {
  importance: 7,
  enableVibrate: true,
  vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
  lightColor: "#FF231F7C",
  showBadge: true,
  sound: 'notificacion.wav',
  name: 'Mi notificacion'
})
```

La respuesta que obtengo de la consola al crear este canal es la siguiente:

```
{
    "audioAttributes": null,
    "bypassDnd": false,
    "description": null,
    "enableLights": false,
    "enableVibrate": true,
    "groupId": null,
    "id": "notificaion",
    "importance": 7,
    "lightColor": "#FF231F7C",
    "lockscreenVisibility": 0,
    "name": "Mi notificacion",
    "showBadge": true,
    "sound": "default",
    "vibrationPattern": [0, 250, 250, 250]
}
```

Y siempre que creo un canal, se muestra en `sound` como `default`, entonces pienso que no se esta seteando bien la propiedad.

Y cuando uso `scheduleNotificationAsync`:

```
await scheduleNotificationAsync({
    content: {
        title: "You've got mail! ",
        sound: 'notificacion.wav', // Provide ONLY the base filename
        vibrate: false
    },
    trigger: {
        seconds: 2,
        channelId: 'notificaion',
    },
});
```

En este caso no suena la notificacions, solo aparece pero sin sonido.

Y al momento de enviar una notificacion usando `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`:

```
{
    "registration_ids": [
        "token..."
    ],
    "notification": {
        "title": "Un nuevo test de notificaciones",
        "body": "Un nuevo body de prueba",
        "sound": "notificacion.wav",
        "channelId": "notificaion",
        "vibrate": false
    }
}
```

Si entra la notificacion y suena pero suena con el tono de notificación por defecto del sistema. Entonces no se si estoy saltando alguna configuración. Tambien he de recalcar que estoy mandando las notificaciones ya despues de compilar y no funciona como deberia.

Expo: 48.0.18

React Native: 0.71.8